# On what the speed of Server-Client depends?

Tags: java, client-server

I am making a java server/client program that sent a lot of images to many users at the same time. and i wand to ask about the speed of this process ..

Is it depends on the LAN speed (i.e. 1 Mbps,...) ? Or what ?

and if it depends on the LAN speed how can i measure how much images can i send at 1 second ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on lots and lots of things:

- speed of the network
- latency of the network
- congestion of the network
- speed of the client machine
- performance of the client program
- speed of the server machine
- performance of server application
- speed of server discs, etc
- load on server, etc

> how can i measure how much images can i send at 1 second ?

You measure it by measuring it!

I think you are really asking how to predict it.  And the answer is that it is almost impossible to predict with any degree of accuracy ... because there are so many variables and there are many "non-linear" effects that impact on the throughput.